# Carga una imagen aleatoria pulsando una tecla

Tags: javascript, jquery, onkeypress

No consigo vincular mis teclas <kbd>UP</kbd>, <kbd>DOWN</kbd>, <kbd>LEFT</kbd> y <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> a la funcion `cambiarImagen`. Con la `id=boton` me sale... pero con teclas determinadas no.

```js
<script>

$(function() {

  var imagenes = [
    '1.jpg',
    '2.jpg',
    '3.jpg',
    '4.jpg',
    '5.jpg'
  ];

  function obtenerImagenAleatoria() {
    return imagenes[Math.floor(Math.random() * imagenes.length)];
  }

  function cambiarImagen() {
    $('#imagen').attr('src', obtenerImagenAleatoria());
  }

  // Imagen inicial
  cambiarImagen();

  // Eventos
  // $('#boton').on('click', cambiarImagen);


});
document.onkeypress = function(event) {
  // per les tecles de lletres cal usar charCode
  //per a les tecles up, down, left, right cal usar keyCode
  var tecla = event.keyCode
  if (tecla == 37) {cambiarImagen();
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <img id="imagen" alt="Imagen aleatoria"><br/>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

`keypress` ignora las flechas, tienes que utilizar `keydown` o `keyup`.

```js
  var imagenes = [
    '1.jpg',
    '2.jpg',
    '3.jpg',
    '4.jpg',
    '5.jpg'
  ];

 function obtenerImagenAleatoria() {
  return imagenes[Math.floor(Math.random() * imagenes.length)];
 }

 function cambiarImagen() {
  $('#imagen').attr('src', obtenerImagenAleatoria());
 }

 cambiarImagen();

document.onkeydown = cambiarImagenEvento;

function cambiarImagenEvento(e) {
 var tecla = event.keyCode;

 if (tecla == 37 || tecla == 38 || tecla == 39 || tecla == 40) {
  cambiarImagen();
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <img id="imagen" alt="Imagen aleatoria" /><br/>

</body>
```